# polymorphic hasMany and belongsTo relationships in ember-data rev 12

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am having trouble implementing what I understand to be a polymorphic relationship using ember-data rev12.

I have the following models:

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend
  lists: DS.hasMany('App.List', { polymorphic: true })

App.Proposal = DS.Model.extend
  lists: DS.hasMany('App.List', { polymorphic: true })

App.Employee = DS.Model.extend
  lists: DS.hasMany('App.List', { polymorphic: true })

App.List = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  #project: DS.belongsTo('App.Project', { polymorphic: true })
```

And I am trying to create a new list from the project router like so.

```
App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  events:
    newList: (project) ->
      lists = project.get('lists')
      list = App.List.createRecord(name: 'list1')
      lists.pushObject(list)
      @store.commit()
```

But the request to the server is setting the polymorphic keys incorrectly.

I was expecting the payload to look like:

```
 { list: { name: list1, listable_type: project, listable_id: 100 } }
```

But got:

```
{ list: { name: list1, project_type: project, project_id: 100 } }
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to define the polymorphic type or key?.

---

**Here is my temporary hack**

https://gist.github.com/arenoir/5409904

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing, based on the current models you have, you don't need to use polymorphic associations. And you may not want to set the `polymorphic` option on both end of the relationship.

If you want to have your payload to contain `listable`, you just need to rename your attribute:

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  listable: DS.belongsTo('App.Project', { polymorphic: true })
```

**UPDATE**

Based on my understanding of your classes, it is a `List` that can belong to different types. So you should define your models like this:

```
App.Listable = DS.Model.extend
  lists: DS.hasMany('App.List')

App.Project = App.Listable.extend

App.Proposal = App.Listable.extend

App.Employee = App.Listable.extend

App.List = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  listable: DS.belongsTo('App.Listable', { polymorphic: true })
```

and the payload will look like this:

```
{list: {name: "list1", listable_type: 'project', listable_id: 100}}
```

I don't know if you also want a list to be added to several listables at the same time. Based on the names of your models, I'm tempted to believe that it's not what you want: a list should contain different objects (project, proposal, employee). and not a project can have multiple lists.

Comment: ok i added some more models to my example. I guess the only way is to create a list model for each parent. The only hangup is if I create a separate list model for each eg(App.ProjectList listable: belongsTo 'Project',{poly:y}) the keys are correct but the json root and url are wrong. eg( put = "api/project_lists" payload = {project_list:{listable_type: project, listable_id: 100}). There must be a way to setup hasMany lists polymorphicly using type and type_id. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: so that works but there are a couple of problems. how do you define multiple polymorphic hasMany relationships for instance project and employee both haveMany tasks. Is it possible to extend from a listable and taskable class?

Comment: also my backend (rails) expects the type to be camelcased. Is it possible specify the type? listable_type: 'project' should actually be listable_type: 'Project'

Comment: For the camelcase issue, there's an open ticket https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/881. I need to work on that.

Comment: A short term solution is to create a new Model that will inherit from Listable and that will add the hasMany relationship for tasks. I'll try to come with a solution for that use case.

Comment: hmm I don't get it. I guess for now I will use a regular DS.hasMany relationship creating a separate model and end point for each (project_lists, employee_lists, proposal_lists....) and serialize/deserilize the foreign_key and foreign_type on the backend.