# Rails-style polymorphic model in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I have the following models in Rails, how would I represent this in Ember/Ember Data?

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :photo, class_name: 'Attachment', as: :attachable
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
end
```

References I've found are [the relevant ember-data pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/750), [the ember-data tests for polymorphic relationships](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/relationships/embedded_polymorphic_has_many_test.js), and [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045708/polymorphic-hasmany-and-belongsto-relationships-in-ember-data-rev-12) but it's difficult to work out a canonical example from them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I now use two different ways of working with rails-style "polymorphic" models. I have updated the code below to show both uses.

**`Attachment` model**: This is "polymorphic" on the Rails side but is always "embedded" on the Ember side. The reason for this is that I currently only need to save/update attachments along with their associated model.

**`Comment` model**: This is polymorphic on both the Rails side and the Ember side.

I have also included code for the `Post` model as it can have multiple attachments and multiple comments.

---

**Rails code:**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :attachments, as: :attachable
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
end

class AttachmentSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :url, :errors
  has_many :comments
end

class CommentSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :body, :created_at, :commentable_id, :commentable_type
  has_one :user
end

class PostSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body, :posted_at, :errors
  has_one :user
  has_many :attachments, embed: :objects, include: true
  has_many :comments
end

class Api::V1::PostsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  before_filter :auth_only!, only: :create

  def create
    # clean / capture ember-data supplied arguments
    params[:post].delete(:user_id)
    attachments_params = params[:post].delete(:attachments)

    @post = current_user.posts.new(params[:post])
    process_attachments(attachments_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: 201
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render json: @post, status: 422
    end
  end

  protected

    def process_attachments(attachments_params)
      return unless attachments_params.present?

      attachments_params.each do |attachment_params|
        # ignore ember-data's additional keys
        attachment_params.delete(:created_at)
        attachment_params.delete(:user_id)

        attachment = @post.attachments.new(attachment_params)
        attachment.user = current_user
      end
    end
end
```

**Ember code:**

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure 'App.Post',
  alias: 'Post'

DS.RESTAdapter.map 'App.Post',
  attachments: { embedded: 'always' }

App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create
    namespace: 'api/v1'

App.Comment = App.Model.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
  commentable: DS.belongsTo('App.Commentable', { polymorphic: true })
  body:       DS.attr('string')
  createdAt:  DS.attr('date')

App.Commentable = App.Model.extend
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')

App.Attachment = App.Commentable.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
  url: DS.attr('string')

App.Post = App.Commentable.extend
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User')
  attachments: DS.hasMany('App.Attachment')

  title: DS.attr('string')
  body: DS.attr('string')
  postedAt: DS.attr('date')

App.PostFormOverlayController = App.OverlayController.extend
  # 'files' attribute is set by a widget that wraps the filepicker.io JS
  updateAttachments: (->
    attachments = @get('attachments')
    attachments.clear()
    @get('files').forEach (file) =>
      attachment = App.Attachment.createRecord({fpFile: file})
      attachments.addObject(attachment)
  ).observes('files')

App.CommentNewController = App.ObjectController.extend
  # this should be instantiated with it's model set to the commentable
  # item. eg. `{{render 'comment/new' content}}`

  save: ->
    transaction = @get('store').transaction()
    comment = transaction.createRecord App.Comment,
      body: @get('body')
      commentable: @get('model')

    comment.one 'didCreate', @, ->
      @set('body', null)

    transaction.commit()
```

Unfortunately my Rails code has become a little polluted with ember-data specific oddities as it tries to send back all the attributes that are defined on the models. (**Note**: There is an [open proposal](https://gist.github.com/tomdale/4263171) for read-only attributes that would solve the params pollution issue)

If anyone knows a better way to approach any of the above please let me know!

**NB:** I'm a little concerned that having models extend from `App.Commentable` will prevent me from having multiple polymorphic attachments on a model, I may need to look for a different way of handling that.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I am trying to use your code as guide to implement mine. I want to clarify if that is the exact way you defined the attachment model in ember-data. I ask because the  links to ember-data polymorphic examples in your question defined the attachment model like this: **App.Attachment = DS.Model.extend({attachable: DS.belongsTo('App.Attachable', { polymorphic: true }) })** and then **App.Attachable = DS.Model.extend({attachments: DS.hasMany('App.Attachment')})**. Also since rails expect back **attachable_type** as a field how do you get that with the current code.

Comment: Right now, yes. I think because my current use of "attachments" is very limited it's working but not fully set up. I'll be making proper use of the polymorphism over the weekend and will update the code here to match. I'm basically sidestepping the `attachable_type` issue by always treating attachments as embedded on the client-side, letting the server-side manage what it needs to.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for clarifying. I will check back over the weekend for the updated code for proper polymorphism. Have a great day.

Comment: @brg I have updated the example to include polymorphic support on the Ember.js side of things. Check out the `comment` related code above.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. I will go through the code. cheers

Comment: One updated needed for Ember Data 1.0 - answered below bec the comments aren't good for large code blocks

Answer (score 3):

The Comment part of Kevin Ansfield's answer (didn't use the Post part) works as of Ember 1.3.0-beta / Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.4 except for the rails serializer, which should now be:

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body, :created_at, :commentable_id, :commentable_type
  has_one :user

  def attributes
    data = super
    data[:commentable] = {id: data[:commentable_id], type: data[:commentable_type]}
    data.delete(:commentable_type)
    data.delete(:commentable_id)
    data
  end
```